# battery rated current!

Tags: battery-charging

Can the battery supply a 25 A? Knowing that the rated discharge time is 20 h?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your (homework) assignment. Luckily you included your attempt at answering it (many forget that). Carefully look at 1. as that already answers your question. Also 2. and 3. already suggest that what you ask can be done.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I thought that if the current exceeded the amount per the rated discharge rate it would be dangerous and may cause fire. In general how to know the peak current a battery can safely provide without overheating?

Comment: @OMAR 'rated' in the battery context means that's the current at which the Ah is specified. A maximum safe discharge current would be specified explicitly as that. Lead acid batteries are usually capable of delivering a very large current. Those intended for auto use have engine starting as one of their intended applications, and so CCA is specified, cold cranking amps, but it's for a limited time and not the full capacity. Non auto batteries may not be intended for such high drain applications, so you'd need to dig around in the data sheet.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks, that's all I wanted to know. Can you make your answer official.